# Как сделать плавное появление блока при нажатии на кнопку

Tags: javascript, html, css, вёрстка, веб-сайт

Нужно сделать так, что бы при нажатии на кнопку сверху выезжал блок на середину страницы. Как такое можно сделать? Буду рад помощи.

Answer (score 1):

Допустим так

```js
document.getElementById('open').addEventListener('click', function(){
  document.getElementById('overlay').classList.add('--show');
});
```

```css
#overlay {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 9990;
  transition: all .5s linear;
  transform: translateY(-100%);
}

#overlay.--show {
  transform: translateY(0%);
}

.modal {
  display: block;
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  background: gray;
}
```

```html
<button id="open">Open</button>

<div id="overlay">
  <div class="modal"></div>
</div>
```